# C# console app logging with Serilog using dependency injection

Tags: c#, serilog

I'm currently working on console application that should be able to log to both console and database using Serilog and built-in Dependency injection to pass Ilogger via constructor to other services. Im running the latest Net Core.

Now my problem with the code below is that in RobotService I'm trying to log all the levels of logs, but I can only see the logs in console. The autocreated table in database called "Logs" is empty.

I'm not quite sure what am I doing wrong. Have anybody dealt with somethins similar?

Thanks a lot for any input.

```
public class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = AppStartup();

        var robotService = ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<RobotService>(host.Services);
        robotService.Run();

        static IConfigurationRoot ConfigSetup()
        {
            return new ConfigurationBuilder()
                                  .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                                  .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                                  .Build();
        }

        static IHost AppStartup()
        {
            var appSettings = ConfigSetup();

            var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
                           .UseSerilog()
                           .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
                           {
                               services.AddTransient<IRobotService, RobotService>();
                               services.AddTransient<IStrategyService, StrategyService>();
                           })
                           .Build();

            Serilog.Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Information()
                .WriteTo.Console()
                .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(
                    connectionString: appSettings.GetConnectionString("DevConnection"),
                    sinkOptions: new MSSqlServerSinkOptions
                    {
                        TableName = "Logs",
                        AutoCreateSqlTable = true
                    },
                    columnOptions: new ColumnOptions()

                ).CreateLogger();
            return host;
        }
    }
}
```